# The same function in two different CPP files. How do I accomplish this?

Tags: c++, header-files

For my homework, this is my assignment:

Create 5 files.  Driver.cpp, f.h, f.cpp, g.h, g.cpp.  f and g should implement a function called hello.  Driver should 
call hello from f and g.

Example Output:

hello from f

hello from g

Press any key to continue . . .

I have all these files created, but what I dont understand is how can the same function hello() exist in two files and be called from the driver.cpp file? any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit: The error I get is "fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found". This is referring to the two hello() functions. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you been learning about namespaces yet?

Comment: We have touched upon them a bit but I'm not very familiar with them.

Comment: C++ has overloading: you can have 2 different functions `hello(int)` and `hello(char)`. This seems silly, but maybe enough for an assignment.

Comment: @anatolyg this is bad practice. Namespaces should be used here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Globally visible entities are allowed to have only one definition. Thus, you can't have the same function `hello()` defined in multiple translation units. There are a few separate approaches how to define equally named functions multiple times:

1. Overloaded function can have the same name as long as they differ in their arguments in some way. For example, you could have each of the `hello()` functions take an argument which differs between the different versions (note: I'm not suggesting this approch). For example:

   ```
   void hello(bool) { std::cout << "hello(bool)\n"; }
   void hello(int)  { std::cout << "hello(int)\n"; }
   ```
2. You can define the names in different namespaces. This makes the fully qualified name actually different, i.e., the conflict is prevented by just using a different scope, e.g.:

   ```
   namespace a { void hello() { std::cout << "a::hello()\n"; }
   namespace b { void hello() { std::cout << "b::hello()\n"; }
   ```
3. Assuming you call your function from a function in the local file, you can move the function from being globally visible to being only locally visible using the `static` keyword. Functions with local visibility do not conflict between different translation units. For example:

   ```
   // file a.cpp
   static void hello() { std::cout << "a.cpp:hello()\n"; }
   void a() { hello(); }

   // file b.cpp
   static void hello() { std::cout << "b.cpp:hello()\n"; }
   void b() { hello(); }
   ```

Which of these versions your teach is actually after, I don't know. Each one has their use, though, and it is useful to know the different variations.

In case someone claims that for completeness I should have included `virtual` functions: note that overriding a function is actually also creating an overload (the `virtual` function in the base and the overriding function differ in the implicity passed object), i.e., the use of `virtual` functions is already covered.

Answer (score 2):

You should use namespaces :

In **f.h**

:

```
namespace mynamespace {
  void hello(); 
}
```

In **f.cpp**

```
void mynamespace::hello()
{
    /... function definition here
}
```

In `main()`

```
int main()
{
   mynamespace :: hello();   // calls hello defined in f.cpp
}
```

For a good introduction to namespaces. [Namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/)